# A strange behaviour of getchar()

Tags: c, io, scanf, getchar

An odd behaviour of getchar() and scanf ocurred in the code below: 
if I insert, in the line `/*K1*/ ch = getchar();` the code works properly in the line `/*k*/`.

I mean, without the calling to `getchar` in the line `/*k1*/` the compiler doesn't ask for a character from the keyboard. On the other hand if  an extra `getchar` is included the program it runs perfectly. Could someone ring me a bell?

```
int INcoord(int n, int **Coo){/*retorna quantidade de dados lida em coordPontos.dat*/
    FILE *fp;           /*Arquivos de leitura e gravacao. */
    char dummy[MAXSTR];      /*informacoes para o usuario nos arquivos de leitura.*/
    int i, j;
    int m;
    char ch;

    printf("Entrada por coordenadas de pontos.\n");
    printf("Leitura das coordenadas com numeros inteiros.\n");
    printf("Arquivo de leitura: coordPontos.dat\n");

    if((fp=fopen("coordPontos.dat","r"))==NULL){
        printf("Arquivo não pode ser aberto.\n"); exit(1); }

    fgets(dummy,MAXSTR,fp); /*Apresentacao do arquivo*/
    fgets(dummy,MAXSTR,fp); /*texto 1*/


    fscanf(fp,"%i ",&m);
    /*K1*/           ch= getchar();

    if(m<n){

        printf("Quantidade de dados menor que o previsto para cadeia do frio.\nVerificar entradas\n");


        printf("Deseja prosseguir programa com a quantidade prevista em coordPontos.dat?\n");

        printf("S - sim\n"); printf("Outra letra - aborta programa\n");
        /*k*/            ch= getchar();

        if (ch=='S' || ch =='s')n=m; /*funçao retorna quantidade de dados usada. */


        else {
            printf("programa abortado.\n");
            exit(1); /*aborta programa */
        }

    }

    fgets(dummy,MAXSTR,fp); /*Texto 2*/
    fscanf(fp,"%i ",&j);


    fclose(fp);

    printf("Teste i = %i, j = %i\n", m, j);

    return n;
}
```

Comment: Please fix the code tags? Read "How to ask a good question" to learn how to do it.

Comment: You should be checking return values of `fgets` and `fscanf`!... and `getchar` returns an `int`, not a `char`. While the return value is in the form of an `int`, you need to ensure that it isn't negative. Negative means error. You can't do this after you convert it to a `char`.

Answer (score 0):

The second call to `getchar()` returns the '\n' character from the stream buffer. Instead use

```
#include <conio.h>

char input = getche();
```

in order to get only one character. Of course you need to include error checking since `getche()` also returns on special keys like F1-F12.

Comment: That's specific to Windows (or MS-DOS).

Comment: @KeithThompson: You're mistaken. `<conio.h>` actually is a UNIX header with windows support.

Comment: getche returns a pointer to `militant_coup_leader`, not `char`.